# Unable to disable SSL verification in IOS

Tags: swift, networking, https

I have an app in Swift 4 which is making a POST request to this domain :

```
qa-api-session.apps.com
```

Where I get a JWT as a response.

While the call works perfectly fine in Postman and curl, it does not work in IOS and I receive this message :

```
nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(724) [0x7fa6d4f0bac0] handshake failed at state 0
2019-09-30 12:30:18.861722-0300 app[4492:188024] Connection 1: received failure notification
2019-09-30 12:30:18.861847-0300 app[4492:188024] Connection 1: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2019-09-30 12:30:18.861967-0300 app4492:188024] Connection 1: encountered error(1:61)
2019-09-30 12:30:18.865759-0300 app4492:188024] Task <XXXX>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
```

I am searching for a way of DISABLING SSL verification and I cant find a straight forward manner. Supposedly I could include some keys on my **info.plist** but its not working at all.

[image]

I just want to make the request and make sure everything is working. Certificate pinning will be done later on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's an SSL issue. You would typically see some context in the log regarding a cert or TLS issue. I didn't see anything in your log other than a handshake issue. If it is an SSL issue, in theory the ```NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads``` in the ATS dictionary will allow you to do insecure HTTP calls (but not recommended). If it's a cert issue or TLS version issue, there are other keys that allow you to set the minimum TLS version. Find those issues often when dealing with older government data APIs.

Comment: @SGraham Is not the message I'm getting specific to ssl?

Comment: @SGraham otherwise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Without more context impossible to say. You will need to write some incremental tests and possibly put a proxy sniffer on the network connection to find out exactly where it's failing.

Comment: @SGraham i actually got it working. It was an error on my side. The URL was not getting populated and my app was attempting to call 'https:///create' . The error message totally confused me but thanks for replying